# How to measure a bearing temperature in a pump?

Tags: sensors, measurements, pumps, temperature, bearings

I found that *Resistance Temperature Detectors* (RTD) are mostly used for bearings, but it's not easy to drill the casing and we need to take a signal out to PLC and LabVIEW.

Is there a sensor that can measure bearing temperature through the casing?

Can I use an IR gun temperature and take a signal from it?

[image: Cross section of Bearing case]

Answer (score 1):

An infrared thermometer (when properly used) will give the temperature of the surface it sees. So if you measure the surface of the bearing casing, you are not seeing the internal bearing temperature. It depends on your application whether the casing temperature is close-enough to be useful in your measurements.

But it seems to me that if the infrared thermometer can see the surface, installing a regular RTD or other temperature sensor on the surface shouldn't be much of an issue. If drilling is too invasive, e.g. silicone-based glues offer good thermal transmission and are resistant to vibration.

To clarify what I mean by "when properly used" above: it is relatively difficult to correctly apply infrared thermometers. The surface roughness and reflectivity affect the reading a lot. For example shiny metal surfaces may act as mirrors and cause the meter to accidentally measure the temperature of the reflected surroundings, instead of the surface you were aiming for. For paper and other translucent materials, it can read the temperature behind the object. However IR thermometers are not able to measure temperatures through metals.

Comment: For the silicone-based glues ,how to make it touch the bearing surface and get it out of the casing to connect it with a sensor ?

Comment: If there is a lubrication system, you might consider measuring the oil temperature. That idea won't work for a sealed bearing, of course.